# Meteor: Count the number of collection item in relational collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, session, meteor, collections

I'm doing a lists/tasks application, I can select the list who display me the good tasks using a session to store which list I'm clicking.
Using the Meteor task board tutorial, I can count how items I have.
the problem is the count system is not related to all lists but to only the list I'm.

I can't understand how to count the items for each lists, and display the counter in front of each lists item.
in the tutorial, the counter is in Session, so do I have to create a new "counter" in the collection, or can I keep the session ?

Some code:
List.js

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('lists', function listsPublication() {
        return Lists.find({
            $or: [
               {private: { $ne: true}},
                {owner: this.userId},
            ],
        });
    });
}

Meteor.methods({

Template.list.helpers({
    incompleteCount() {
        return Tasks.find({ listId: Session.get('listId'), checked: { $ne: true } }).count();
    },

Template.list.events({
    'click .list-selected' (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var list = $(event.currentTarget).attr('list-id');
        Session.set('listId', list);
    },
```

Body.js

```
Template.body.helpers({
    tasks() {
        const instance = Template.instance();

        if (instance.state.get('hideCompleted')) {
            return Tasks.find({
                listId: Session.get('listId'),
                checked: { $ne: true },
            }, { sort: Session.get("sort_order") });
        }
        return Tasks.find({listId: Session.get('listId')}, { sort:      Session.get("sort_order")});
     },

     lists() {
         return Lists.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
     },

});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like you need to subscribe to all lists, then do your filtering on the client for the counts.  An alternative would be to aggregate the data, either though an aggregation, or custom publish, or simply writing the final counts to a separate aggregation collection.

Comment: Hey I just edited the post cause I think I subscribe good to all lists. I don't understand how I can do the filter on the client It's what i'm trying to do by the helper..

Comment: instead of having a helper that returns all lists, it would be better to have a helper that you pass in the list you want it and returns just that list. I would even nest my templates so I had a template that handled displaying a single list. That is (or was, unless it's changed) the preferred way to use Blaze...to create logical nested templates for your components. This way the reactivity is relegated to the smallest component possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @CodeChimp, I could find the way just using a param in my helper:

```
    incompleteCount(listId) {
        return Tasks.find({ listId: listId, checked: { $ne: true } }).count();
    },
```

And the template (using jade):

```
   .ui.teal.left.pointing.label
        span {{incompleteCount this._id}}
```

Using the search I did before in one list, but I just added the param instead of the session.get() who just get the active list ...

Thanks